# How many points can you define before a function that passes through them doesnt exist anymore?

Tags: functions

If we have a function with real input and real output and we define N points that pass through the graph of the function, how big can N get before there is no function that can pass through all of them? Is N finite, countably infinite or uncountably infinite? This function can be defined using all math symbols like arithmetic operations, sums, integrals, products etc.

Comment: This is called interpolation. If $N$ is finite, there's always a polynomial function that interpolates a set of points. If you don't need the function to be continuous, then there's always a trivial function passing through all sets of points. If it's countably infinite there are sets of points that force a discontinuity (therefore a continuous solution doesn't exist).

Comment: Simple example on $\mathbb R$: for positive rational numbers, assign the value $1$, and for negative rational numbers, assign the value $0$. There's no continuous function that passes through these points, because it would have to satisfy $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = 1$ and $\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = 0$.

Comment: @AnilCh thank you for your time.